# Flutter simple_slider installation problem

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

flutter_cache_manager and cached_network_image is successfully instaled.

flutter_cache_manager: ^1.1.3
cached_network_image: ^1.1.3

When try install **simple_slider: ^0.0.2**  get below error

```
Because every version of simple_slider depends on cached_network_image ^0.4.1 and first_flutter_app depends on cached_network_image ^1.1.3, simple_slider is forbidden.

So, because first_flutter_app depends on simple_slider ^0.0.2, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
simple_slider: any
```

hope it helped